# Magento incorrect amount while paying

Tags: magento

I have used this to create plugin http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/ it is working fine and grand total is displaying correct; But when users pay the do not see this amount included in that;

Can you let me know what could be wrong?

Thanks!

[Total screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rN8p7.png)

You can see that Totals are being added up in grand total but when users pay they don't see the amount for Refundable Damage/Loss Deposit; That's why it is still coming as due amount.

Comment: what amount? are taxes missing? is shipping missing? We cant read your mind

Comment: I created a module from above given link; That is custom total; I am uploading pic in my post;

Comment: you can't create a module from above given link, I mean it's just a skeleton (files and folders), not real working extension with business logic inside

Comment: i know that i applied my logic to add the custom amount in total. and it displays correctly everywhere. but whn invoice is created ftom admin panel for an order this amount is not included in invoice

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem ; It comes from the generated extension from silksoftware;

If you have similar problem; open the file in this directory

/www/app/code/local/Company/ExtraFee/Model/Order/Invoice/Total

and replace this line

```
 $DepositTotal = $order->getDepositTotal();
 if ($DepositTotal&&count($order->getInvoiceCollection())==0) {
```

with

```
 $orderDepositTotal= $order->getDepositTotal();
if ($orderDepositTotal&&count($order->getInvoiceCollection())==0) {
```

:)

Thanks guys for no help :p I ended up debugging it myself and feeling pretty good :p

```
   <?php
   class Comapny_ExtraFee_Model_Order_Invoice_Total_Deposit
   extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice_Total_Abstract
   {
             public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice $invoice)
       {
        $order=$invoice->getOrder();
    $DepositTotal = $order->getDepositTotal();
    if ($DepositTotal&&count($order->getInvoiceCollection())==0) {
        $invoice->setGrandTotal($invoice->getGrandTotal()+$orderDepositTotal);
        $invoice->setBaseGrandTotal($invoice->getBaseGrandTotal()+$orderDepositTotal);
    }
    return $this;
}
   }
```